# C++ Structs in arrays

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

Am i doing this right, I want a map with a Integer as key, and struct as value. What is the easiest way to, say I want the object at `1`. How do I retrieve the value of `isIncluded`? The last two lines in the code, I tried doing it, but then I realized I don´t really know what is the way to retrieving values of structs in a numbered Map array.

Do I need to call `cells.get(1)` and assign that to a new temporarely struct to get its values?

```
/** set ups cells map. with initial state of all cells and their info*/
void setExcludedCells (int dimension)
{
    // Sets initial state for cells
    cellInfo getCellInfo;
    getCellInfo.isIncluded = false;
    getCellInfo.north = 0;
    getCellInfo.south = 0;
    getCellInfo.west = 0;
    getCellInfo.east = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= (pow(dimension, 2)); i++)
    {
        cells.put(i, getCellInfo);
    }
    cout << "Cells map initialized. Set [" << + cells.size() << "] cells to excluded: " << endl;
    cells.get(getCellInfo.isIncluded);
    cells.get(1);
}
```

the Map, is declared as an private instance variable like this:

```
struct cellInfo {
    bool isIncluded;
    int north;  // If value is 0, that direction is not applicable (border of grid).
    int south;
    int west;
    int east;
};
Map<int, cellInfo> cells;       // Keeps track over included /excluded cells
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `cells`?

Comment: Do you mean you want a `std::map<int, cellInfo>` structure?

Comment: It´s a private instance variable: Map<int, cellInfo> cells;

Comment: What is the declaration of `Map`?

Comment: it´s not a map, but a Map (from Stanford C++ libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for Map](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/Map-class.html), it appears that `.get()` returns a `ValueType`.

You would use it thus:

```
// Display item #1
std::cout << cells.get(1).isIncluded << "\n";
std::cout << cells.get(1).north << "\n";
```

Or, since the lookup is relatively expensive, you could copy it to a local variable:

```
// Display item #1 via initialized local variable
cellInfo ci = cells.get(1);
std::cout << ci.isIncluded << " " << ci.north << "\n";

// Display item #2 via assigned-to local variable
ci = cells.get(2);
std::cout << ci.isIncluded << " " << ci.north << "\n";
```

---

My best advice is to use the standard library's `std::map` data structure instead:

```
// Expensive way with multiple lookups:
std::cout << cells[1].isIncluded << " " << cells[1].north << "\n";

// Cheap way with one lookup and no copies
const cellinfo& ci(maps[1]);
std::cout << ci.isIncluded << " " << ci.north << "\n";
```